# How to stop emerge showing "unnecessary" blockages

Tags: package-management, upgrade, gentoo, emerge

I am usually updating my `~amd64` Gentoo system using `emerge -avNuD --backtrack=100 @world`. I do however often get the following type of blockages.

```
sys-libs/ncurses:5

  (sys-libs/ncurses-6.0:5/6::gentoo, ebuild scheduled for merge) pulled in by
    (no parents that aren't satisfied by other packages in this slot)

  (sys-libs/ncurses-5.9-r4:5/5::gentoo, installed) pulled in by
>=sys-libs/ncurses-5.2:5/5= required by (sys-devel/bc-1.06.95-r2:0/0::gentoo, installed)
    (and 3 more with the same problem)
```

I do fully understand that blockages may occur if different versions demand different thing. But in cases like this one, a package would only be updated, because an update is available. Even though it is not (yet) supported by any other ebuild.

Just using `emerge -u @world` will run, but it is not enough for e.g., performing `emerge --depclean` afterwards.

Is there any way to perform a deep world update which automatically ignores (only) those changes which would lead to blockages?

Comment: I have the same problem, I see that there must be a problem with slots used by different `ncurses` ebuilds, but I don't fully understand where the problem comes from and cannot find a solution...

Comment: Although not an answer; freenode.net has #gentoo channel. People there are very responsive, and will probably help you with your problem quickly.

If they do find a solution, you can come back and post it here for future reference.

Comment: @wrzasa I did not ask how to resolve this specific blockage manually (I know how to do). My question was more generally how to call portage such that as many packages as possible are updated, but not packages that would result in blockages with other packages.

Comment: @MatthewRock OK then, sorry for messing with your question. Apparently I didn't get your goal. Feel free to just remove my edits.

Comment: @wrzasa Hey, thanks, but it's not my question :)

Comment: @MatthewRock Woops... I should have written that to Tim ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I just synced my potrage tree and `ncurses` got updated. After this sync I added

```
=sys-devel/llvm-3.5.0 -ncurses
```

to my `packages.use` since on my system `llvm` pulled the problematic version on `ncurses` in slot 5. This solved the blocks in my case.

I think I can live without `ncurses` in `llvm` for now...